# How to convert a JSON array to a key value array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, key, nvd3.js

I hope I am asking this correctly.

I have an array `notes` in which each element is a JSON line. So for example:

```
//notes[0] contains this line
{
"id":"23",
"valuee":"129",
"datee":"2016-04-05T15:20:08.218+0100"
}

//notes[1] contains this line:
{
"id":"24",
"valuee":"131",
"datee":"2016-04-05T15:20:10.272+0100"
}
```

What I want is to convert the previous array to something like this, so I can use it to plot a linewithfocus chart with nvd3:

```
  //notes[0] contains this line
{
key:"23",
values:[{x:"129",y:"2016-04-05T15:20:08.218+0100"}]

//notes[1] contains this line:
{
key:"24",
values:[{x:"131",y:"2016-04-05T15:20:10.272+0100"}]
```

How can I do it? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in following way

```
notes.map((note) => {
    return {
        key: note.id,
        values: [{
            x: note.valuee,
            y: note.datee
        }]
    } 
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The solution was way simpler than what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.map`

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "23",
  "valuee": "129",
  "datee": "2016-04-05T15:20:08.218+0100"
}, {
  "id": "24",
  "valuee": "131",
  "datee": "2016-04-05T15:20:10.272+0100"
}]

var result = data.map(function(o) {
  return {
    key: o.id,
    values: {
      x: o.valuee,
      y: o.datee
    }
  }
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result,0,4) + "</pre>");
```